# Running process remotely with PowerShell returns The request is not supported

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that running remotely process on a list of computers.

Using this code returns "Access is denied" error:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName srv12-01 -Credential "cloud\user2" -ScriptBlock{
    $creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('cloud\summer', $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Hall1290' -AsPlainText -Force));
    Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $creds;
}
```

And using this code give returns "The request is not supported"

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName srv12-01 -Credential "cloud\user2" -Authentication Credssp -ScriptBlock{
    $creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('cloud\summer', $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Hall1290' -AsPlainText -Force));
    Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $creds;
}
```

Few Notes:

- I enabled CredSSP on the machine that i am running the code from and on the destination machine
- I have another machines that are newer than windows server 2012\r2 and it works like a charm.
- tried to update the server with the latest PS (5.1)
- Enabled PS-Remoting on the destination

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any of these points in this forum post relevant? https://powershell.org/forums/topic/pssession-credssp-request-not-supported-error/

Comment: Wow thanks, I tried to search online for posts talking abput "The request is not supported" but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

trebleCode gave me that link: https://powershell.org/forums/topic/pssession-credssp-request-not-supported-error/
And this has solved out my problem.

The problem was that the endpoint didn't have the right update of Oracle CredSSP, so I just updated the machine with windows update.